# Generate diff file of a specific commit in Git

Tags: git, git-diff

When the head is at a particular commit, I want to get a diff file so that I can reduce the head to one more level down and then try the testing functionality with and without applying the diff file. So is there a way to generate a diff file of a specific commit.

Even though there is a way to change the head before and after commit, this method comes in more handy.

Comment: you can see changes of a commit by `gti diff <commit-sha> -p`

Comment: I have no idea what you are actually asking here, but you can diff any two commits: `git diff commit1 commit2`. You can also limit the output of `git diff` of any two commits to specified files: `git diff c1 c2 -- path1 path2`, for instance.

Comment: @SajibKhan that doesn't work for me.  I have to use `git diff <commit-sha>^!`

Answer (score 45):

See the changes of a specific commit:

```
git diff <commit-sha> -p
```

Or,

```
git show --decorate <commit-sha>    # See 'Author', 'Date' and 'diff'
```

See the diff of two commits:

```
git diff <commit1> <commit2>
```

See the `file` changes for a specific commit:

```
git show <commit>:<file>
```

See all the changes for a time duration (say, *1 day*):

```
git whatchanged --since="1 day ago" -p
git whatchanged --since="1 day ago" -p <file>   # See changes for a specific file only
```

Comment: `git diff <commit-sha> -p` gives me exactly the same as without the `-p`. I.e. the diff between after that commit was comitted and the currnet working directory.

Comment: `git diff <commit-sha> -p` does not show the diffs for `<commit-sha>`.  To show the diffs committed for a given hash, I have to use `git diff <commit-sha>^!`.

Comment: What @JeffLearman said is true.  As the docs describe, simply listing a single `<commit-sha>` is asking for the diffs between that commit and the current `HEAD`, which may be a considerable distance in the repo graph.  Instead, `<commit-sha>^!` is a shortcut for "the single commit specified by this object, but using syntax that `git` will see as a range of revisions (as required by diff/log/etc)".

Answer (score 17):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get a diff for a file with one level below HEAD.

To check the file difference from the current HEAD to one level before:

```
git diff HEAD^1 filename
```

The number *1* is for the level you want to compare.

You can also get a diff using the SHA-1 hash also. To see all commits with their SHA-1 use:

```
git log --oneline
```

And then you can use the SHA-1 hash to get a diff
to compare the current HEAD with a specific commit. Use:

```
git diff commitSHA filename
```

If you want to get all differences between two commits, you can use:

```
git diff commitSHA1..commitSHA2 filename
```

Answer (score 13):

From `gitrevisions(7)`:

> The r1^! notation includes commit r1 but excludes all of its parents. By itself, this notation denotes the single commit r1.

This works to show the diff for a single commit. E.g., you can do:

```sh
git log --oneline | grep thingamabob
```

This will give you the short SHA-1 hash, so then you can see the diff for that commit:

```sh
git diff 'b7f57543^!'
```

Comment: Most useful answer imo because it doesn't require you to hunt down 2 hashs or remember more than 1.

Comment: This works, thanks! I'm confused about the terminology used though. `The r1^! notation includes commit r1 but excludes all of its parents.` Shouldn't this be `excludes all its children`? When I do git diff <commit>, I see changes from <commit> and all of its children (not parents). So it seems the notation in question excludes its *childrens* changes.

Answer (score 2):

To generate a diff file you would forward the output to a file. Say `commit1` is the commit you want the diff for:

```
git diff <commit-before-commit1> <commit1> > commit1.diff
```