# How to view the changes between start and finished in a file that has undergone numerous commits?

Tags: git, diff

Lets say a file undergoes a number of modifications and commits.

Eventually those changed also need to be extracted for another baseline.

Here is the scenario.

```
 - Start Here.
 - Edit & Commit 1
 - Edit & Commit 2
 - Edit & Commit 3
   :
   :
 - Edit & Commit n
 - Final Commit
```

Using gitk and it lists each individual commit. 
Usually this is a decent tool, but in this specific scenario each Edit & Commit may add new code and remove code done from a previous commit. Working in the scenario to extract code is cumbersome as you may find the same code is added/removed/moved/added someplace else......

All I want to see is the Before (Start Here) and After (Final Commit) and not concerned about the various commits.

Is there a tool available that allows me to simply view the changes between "Start HERE" and "Final Commit"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate diff file of a specific commit in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42357521/generate-diff-file-of-a-specific-commit-in-git)

Comment: Unless I am not implementing it correctly, I am not seeing what I am expecting to see.  I did a "git log <filename>" first. There were 3 commits on this file. Then I executed "gitk <1st commit>  <2nd commit>  <filename" and there were numerous items missing.

Comment: `git diff`, not `gitk`.

Comment: Yes, same results with "git diff" or gitk . There are considerable changes not visible when including commits.

Answer (score 1):

`gitk` has a "Mark this commit" action,

once you have marked the first commit you will see extra actions on a second commit, such as : "Compare with marked commit".

---

More generally : you are looking for a way to view the diff between two commits ("Start HERE" and "Final Commit").

There are many other ways to do that :

- in a terminal :

  ```
  git diff <commitA> <commitB> -- some/file
  ```
- opening a graphical diff tool:

  ```
  git difftool <commitA> <commitB> -- some/file
  # look for 'diff.tool' in 'git help config' for details on difftool
  ```
- all gui frontends to git (like `gitk`, but also `git gui`, `git-kraken`, `git-extensions` etc ...) have a way to compare two commits,

  either with a "mark first commit" / "diff with second commit" (as in `gitk`),
  or by allowing to select two commits (ctrl+Click) and a "diff selected commits" action

---

To tell `gitk` to focus on a particular set of files (or a single file) :

you can start `gitk` with filtering options:

```
gitk -- some/files
```

or, once `gitk` is open, you can execute the "View > New view ..." action,
a dialog will open, with a text field "Enter files and directories to include, one per line" near the bottom.

Comment: That seems to do a comparison between all the files between the 2 commits. If there are 10 files involved total, it may only show 3 files affected by this commit. Is it possible to focus on 1 specific file at a time?

Comment: Also, if a file has 3 commits, do you mark your first commit on a file or would you mark the final commit of the fix before your fix? I am wondering because if I choose the first commit, won't it miss the original changes?

Comment: one way I know : you can filter files when opening gitk : `gitk some/file` or `gitk -- some/file` ; diffs will then only display modifications on this file

Comment: (to your second comment) : git actually stores the whole content of each file in each of its commits ; the diff is between "the whole content in commitA" and "the whole content in commitB".

Comment: In the one file I happen to be working with there are two commits. Looking at each individual commit isn't too bad for this one file, but when doing the "compare" there are numerous other lines with -+ and - and none of these lines are actually part of the commit. By doing the compare it adds about twice as many lines to the output with various -, or -+ and these are completely unrelated and unmodified making actually a bit more cumbersome to extract the changes.

Comment: @unhabdledException : You are right, it looks like gitk does not keep the file filtering when diffing two commits. Do evaluate if `git diff -- the/file` in a terminal or `git difftool -- the/file` are closer to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had to do.
Not certain if it is what the above posts mentioned or not.

```
 - My Final Edit & Commit 
 - My Edit & Commit 2
 - My Initial Edit & Commit 1    <----Don't use this.
 - Someone Else Edit & Commit    <----Use this as the first commit
 - Original File
```

Originally I was doing the following diff and it was not showing me all the changes.

```
 git diff <My Initial Edit & Commit 1> <My Final Edit & Commit> <myFile>
```

What I had to do :

```
 git diff <Someone Else Edit & Commit> <My Final Edit & Commit> <myFile>
```

Once I did the commit prior to my first commit I was able to see all the changes in a single summary.

Not certain if that is what the above responses were actually stating.

Also, if the file only has my 3 changes and no changes prior or commits to reference, I find myself with the original issue of not seeing all the modifications.